# JavaScript "string +=" error

Tags: javascript, string

Why is this code:

```
const buttonDOT = document.getElementById('gridButton_dot')
      .addEventListener('click', function(){mainDisplay.value += '.'
  })
```

resulting in my display showing .5 instead of 5. and why the heck is it logging 5. in the console?? Even worse if I press another key it gets corrected to 5.1 for example D:

NOTE: I'm making a calculator which has a display/input that has a direction:RTL and maybe it's also important that I mention I build an app in electron

Comment: With only that code the display shows **nothing**. [mcve] please.

Comment: Because of `direction:RTL` . You've probably messed it with `text-align:right`

Comment: It’s the RTL. Why do you have that?

Comment: Well yes, that's working now, but isn't this still a bug cause it fixes itself after I update the display? and pls write a answer so I can accept it

Comment: @Aduentix You can write one yourself. On [so] we encourage users to self-answer their questions if they know how to solve it.

Comment: Sure but he got it right. :)

Answer (score 0):

So it looks like there is a problem with: **direction:RTL.**
I used **text-align:right** instead and now everything works fine.

Thanks to **Kosh Very** for providing this suggestion

Elias